# How to upload my code or my .hex file to nodeMCU in proteus simulation?

Tags: nodemcu, proteus

I am using Proteus and trying to upload my code to nodeMCU. I have never used Proteus before and don't how to upload my code( or if it will take a .hex file like arduino). I have successfully compiled my code on ArduinoIDE. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When you verify a code in arduino it creates a temp hex file in 
C:\Users\Your user name\AppData\Local\Temp
in temp folder after you verify there should be folder name arduniobuild the .hex file should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of generating a hex file is by selecting the sketch menu in the arduino IDE and a drop down of options appears. Select the export binary.... For the Proteus software, it allows you to perform simulation on the picked devices. After launching Proteus, on your nodeMCU,embed the hex file. In Proteus if you don't embed the code on the arduino uno or Mega 2560, nothing works. Just right click on the component and a pop up appears. Arduino works on serial communication. So embedding the hex file on any arduino component makes simulation possible.